# How to check and validation the variable in the main class of Java using JUnit?

Tags: java, junit

I want to check the variable in the main method using JUnit, how to write the test file?

**Main Class:**

```
package junit;

public class MyClasss {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x = 20;
        double y = 15.5;
        double result = x + y;
        System.out.print(result);
    }
}
```

**Junit Test**

```
package junit;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class JUnitMyClassTest {
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      private final PrintStream oPrintStream = System.out;

      @Before
      public void setUpStream() {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outputStream));
      }

      @After
      public void restoreStream() {
        System.setOut(oPrintStream);
      }

        @Test
        public void myResultTest() {
            junit.MyClasss.main(null);
            assertEquals("MyClass Double Result", "35.5", outputStream.toString());
        }
}
```

i want to check if the variable **x** is **int** with value is **20**, and then also the **result** variable must be **double**. How i write the JUnit test to get that variable and validation that variable?

Comment: you can't unit test that. You can execute the main method, sure, but that's it. when that method is finished executing, the variables can't be checked, because they no longer exist

Answer (score 0):

You cannot work with the value of local variables in unit tests, no matter in which method they occur.

Extract the calculation into a separate method (instance method would be easier to test), then you can test that method. Still it will be hard to test the call to a method from another static method.